# jQuery $.css() function not interpreting "animation-delay" properly (in webkit browsers!)

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, animation, webkit

***Edited - linked the wrong codepen***
***This only seems to happen in webkit browsers. In firefox it works as intened. In IE, the right inline-style is added but it doesn't add the prefix(even if I specify 'ms-animation-delay' in the javascript instead of just 'animation-delay'***

I'm playing with a codepen trying to replicate some Google Material effects ( I know they have them in polymer, I just wanted to try to replicate some of the effects for fun). For some odd reason, jQuery is wrongly putting "animation: [value]" into the inline-styling instead of "animation-delay: [value]". Can anyone explain why and how to make a work around?

Here's the codepen: [link](http://codepen.io/nickgofly/pen/DAhuK)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lis = $("li"), str;

  for(var x=2; x<= lis.length; x++){
    str=(0.2+ 0.1*(x-2))+"s";
    lis.eq(x-1).css({"animation-delay": str});
  }
});
```

This also occurs with transition-delay.

Comment: Seems to add the style to the elements for me when I add the script ?

Comment: why do you think it set the `animation` instead of `animation-delay`? Looks like changing the `animation-delay` does not affect the animation at all. To change the `animation-delay`, you have to change the `animation` with a ***new keyframes name*** to change the  running animation.

Comment: The codepen that I linked to was the wrong one. The new one should present my problem. The other one had the animation-delay manually put on the css so that's why it probably worked for you guys. If it still continues to work, then tell me what browser your using lol. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: King Kong, you can put animation-delay on the element you're targeting. if you look, that's how the original codpen did the delays (scroll down on the css) http://codepen.io/leonard/pen/ytqjJ/ . I'm just trying to replicate that and make a version that can scale to more elements without having to manually put the animation-delays

Comment: @user3718546 how the code in codepen does is ***via CSS***, if using script you have to change the `animation` property to a totally different `animation` (with a new keyframes name).

Comment: how do you go about making an animation through js? Can you post a jsfiddle or codepen demonstrating how to dynamically change animation-delays, whichever implementation (if any!) works would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like FireFox allows you to update the animation via the sub-properties such as we can change the animation delay by just changing the property `animation-delay`. It's a pity that other browsers (Chrome, Opera, IE...) don't support that way of updating animation. That means to change the animation, you have to set the `animation-name` to a totally new name (new keyframes name). So if you just want to change the `animation-delay`, you may have to create 2 keyframes with different names (but they should have the same inner key rules, just different names). And then reapply the whole `animation` with the new name and the desired `animation-delay` like this:

```
//the current animation:
animation: display 5s infinite;
//the updated animation:
animation: display2 5s 1s infinite;
```

As you can see, the difference is in the name (`display2` instead of `display`) and we added a delay of `1s`. That way works in all browsers.

However I notice that you just want to apply the animation using script, so the simplest thing to do is just remove all the animation in the CSS code (just keep the keyframes) and apply the animation using script, that way you don't need to create the clone (`display2`)  of `display` keyframes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var lis = $("li"), str;
 for(var x=1; x<= lis.length; x++){
   str=(200+ 100*(x-1))+"ms";    
   lis.eq(x-1).css({"animation": "display 5s " + str + " infinite"});
 }
});
```

### [Updated Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tgrle).

Comment: Yeah I tried straight up setting the animation delay property with .attr("style","[property]") but that didn't work so I figured that the browsers just didn't support it. I ended up just using a for-loop with setTimeouts, your solution works well though. I hope browsers support these changes as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
.attr('style','-webkit-animation-delay:'+str+';animation-delay:'+str);
```

Comment: Adding also some details and explanations could prove useful for SO users. Just a thought :)