# Set value for animation-delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, animation

Is it possible to set dynamic value for css property **animation-delay** inline into HTML code. Something like this:

```
 <u>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in items" style="animation-delay: item.id/10 + 's'">
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use javascript variables in html code. You should use jQuery [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to set this style attribute value

HTML:

```
    <u>
        <li id="animLi" data-ng-repeat="item in items"></li>
    </ul>
```

JS:

```
    $("#animLi").css( "animation-delay", item.id/10 + 's' );
```

---

notice that you can have some problems with above in web-kit browsers. Compare with: [jQuery $.css() function not interpreting "animation-delay" properly (in webkit browsers!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592846/jquery-css-function-not-interpreting-animation-delay-properly-in-webkit-b)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="item in items" style="animation-delay: {{item.id/10}}s"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It does not work. I am getting an issue every time when try to set property "animation-delay"  with value(variable). It accepts only hardcoded string

Comment: Found a working  solution for me: try to add to your ng-repeat `"track by $index"` and replace with 'item.id' for debug pourpose. 

If no error is given the problem is beside the item id. Make sure it is always `!== null` or `typeof "number"`. To inspect what 'item.id' is rendered try add `{{item.id}}` inside the <li> DOM element and see the real value.