# Changed CSS class before applying class does not take effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Been at this for a while and was wondering if someone could give a pointer:

Essentially, I'm trying to update a css animation's class before applying it to the element to be animated but the updated elements in the class won't apply. In the example, the iteration count, duration, and delay do not apply when I try the animation but if I have them in the class already, they work fine (they're commented out right now).

Any ideas or another method to update animations before applying them? Would I have to make separate classes for each variation of my animation?"

Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".blsAnimation").css("animation-iteration-count:", "1, 2, 1, 1");
  $(".blsAnimation").css("animation-duration", "1s, 2s, 2s, 1s");
  $(".blsAnimation").css("animation-delay", "1s, 1s, 6s, 7s");
  $('#bls').addClass('blsAnimation');
});
```

```css
/*circle for bls*/
.circle {
  height: 10vw;
  width: 10vw;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40vh;
}

.blsAnimation {
  animation-name: moveCenterLeft, moveLeftRight, moveLeftCenter, fadeOut;
  /*animation-duration: 1000ms, 2000ms, 1000ms, 1000ms;*/
  /*animation-delay: 1000ms, 2000ms, 6000ms,7000ms;*/
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out, ease-in-out;
  /*animation-iteration-count: 1, 2, 1, 1;*/
  animation-direction: normal, alternate, normal, normal;
  animation-fill-mode: none, none, none, forwards;
}


/*animations for moving back and forth*/
@keyframes moveCenterLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-40vw);
  }
}

@keyframes moveLeftRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-40vw);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(40vw);
  }
}

@keyframes moveLeftCenter {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-40vw);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- If IE use the latest rendering engine -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Coach Rory</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="script.js"></script>
    <script type ='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/screenfull.js/3.2.0/screenfull.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <div>

  <div class="circle" id = "bls"></div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried with a single animation instead of the set of animations? Maybe jquery is having problems with the set of animations because it can work with one at a time, not like the css shorthand you are using

Comment: @mnemosdev I haven't tried with a single css animation but the application I want has to have a chain of animations since the number of left right movements have to be iterated a variable number of times. 

Is there a way to redo the animation with the circle starting and ending in the middle while being able to control the left and right iterations?

Comment: have you tried passing an array with the options instead of a string of options?

Comment: like ("animation-count", ["1","2","1","1","1"])

Comment: Your class name $("#blsAnimation") starts with #. Not sure that's allowed. The addClass function will assume the name starts with a dot.

Comment: @Gerard Good catch! I must have changed it while rewriting it. The problem still persists though :/

Comment: @mnemosdev Just tried entering it as an array, no change. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Now there's a comma missing between 6s and 7s: css("animation-delay", "1s, 1s,6s 7s");

Comment: @Gerard Thanks for the help. Sorry for the last minute edits. Keep trying to remove things that don't need to be there.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592846/jquery-css-function-not-interpreting-animation-delay-properly-in-webkit-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your jquery code with this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bls').addClass('blsAnimation');
    $(".blsAnimation").css({"animation-iteration-count": "1, 2, 1, 1","animation-duration": "1s, 2s, 2s, 1s","animation-delay": "1s, 1s, sideToSideDelay, fadeOutDelay"});
});
```

Comment: Yess! It works! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  //Manipulate animations here!
  var animations = [{
      'animation-iteration-count': 1,
      'animation-duration': '3s',
      'animation-name': 'moveCenterLeft',
      'animation-direction': 'normal',
    },
    {
      'animation-iteration-count': 2,
      'animation-duration': '2s',
      'animation-name': 'moveLeftRight',
      'animation-direction': 'alternate',
    },
    {
      'animation-iteration-count': 1,
      'animation-duration': '1s',
      'animation-name': 'moveLeftCenter',
      'animation-direction': 'normal',
    },
    {
      'animation-iteration-count': 1,
      'animation-duration': '1s',
      'animation-name': 'fadeOut',
      'animation-direction': 'normal',
    }
  ]

  function handleAnim(anim) {
    var current = anim[0];
    if (current) {
      $('#bls').css(current).one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
        function(e) {
          anim.shift();
          handleAnim(anim);
        });
    }
  };

  handleAnim(animations);

});
```

```css
/*circle for bls*/

.circle {
  height: 10vw;
  width: 10vw;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40vh;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out
}


/*animations for moving back and forth*/

@keyframes moveCenterLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-40vw);
  }
}

@keyframes moveLeftRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-40vw);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(40vw);
  }
}

@keyframes moveLeftCenter {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-40vw);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0vw);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/screenfull.js/3.2.0/screenfull.min.js"></script>

<div class="circle" id="bls"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use jquery selector with class blsAnimation you might think that you are referring to CSS class. However $(.class) selector selects DOM elements that has ".class" attribute. Since you dont have this class at the beginning on '#bls' element, it is not selected. Therefore, it is not applied to DOM element(DOM element is tag with id 'bls' in this case).

Your order should be

```
$('#bls').addClass(blsAnimation);
//then change CSS here by referencing $('.blsAnimation')
```

by this way it can select element with 'bls' id when you change css of

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I didn't realise it worked like that.